# why Load(byte[]) lead to one more AssemblyResolve event and LoadFrom(filepath) does not

Tags: .net, winforms, load, log4net, .net-assembly

I am using log4net.I put "log4net.dll" in a place different to "log4net.config".And i load "log4net.dll" dymanically in AssemblyResolve event.When i using `Load(byte[])`,AssemblyResolve will be tigger requesting `log4net` when `log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(somepath\\log4net.config)` is called later.
But when i changed to use `LoadFrom(filepath)` in AssemblyResolve ,it will be fine.does this two method any different.the "log4net.config" look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>
  </configSections>
  <log4net>
    <logger name="modifyLogger">
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="modifyLogFile" />
    </logger>

    <appender  name="modifyLogFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender,log4net" >
      <param name= "File" value= "log/modify/"/>
      <param name= "AppendToFile" value= "true"/>
      <param name= "MaxSizeRollBackups" value= "10"/>
      <param name= "StaticLogFileName" value= "false"/>
      <param name= "DatePattern" value= "yyyy-MM-dd&quot;.log&quot;"/>
      <param name= "RollingStyle" value= "Composite"/>
      <maximumFileSize value="10MB"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <param name="Header" value="&#xD;&#xA;----------------------application startup--------------------------&#xD;&#xA;" />
        <param name="Footer" value="&#xD;&#xA; ----------------------application shutdown--------------------------&#xD;&#xA;" />
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} --%-5p-- %m%n" />
      </layout>
    </appender>

    <logger name="logLogger">
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="LogFile" />
    </logger>
    
    <appender  name="LogFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender,log4net" >
      <param name= "File" value= "log/"/>
      <param name= "AppendToFile" value= "true"/>
      <param name= "MaxSizeRollBackups" value= "10"/>
      <param name= "StaticLogFileName" value= "false"/>
      <param name= "DatePattern" value= "yyyy-MM-dd&quot;.log&quot;"/>
      <param name= "RollingStyle" value= "Composite"/>
      <maximumFileSize value="10MB"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <param name="Header" value="&#xD;&#xA;----------------------application startup--------------------------&#xD;&#xA;" />
        <param name="Footer" value="&#xD;&#xA; ----------------------application shutdown--------------------------&#xD;&#xA;" />
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} --%-5p-- %m%n" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    
    <appender>
    </appender>
    <logger name="logApp">
      <level value="ALL" />
    </logger>
    <root>
    </root>
  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the remarks section of the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.loadfrom?view=net-5.0#System_Reflection_Assembly_LoadFrom_System_String_), there is a difference:

> The load-from context allows an assembly to be loaded from a path not included in probing, and yet **allows dependencies on that path to be found and loaded** because the path information is maintained by the context.